# Probably my external HD had changed filesystem when I used it on Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, filesystems

I have an external HD mostly used in my Win7. But I transfered some files to it using Ubuntu 12, and now it isn't being reconized in my Windows. I am being prompted to format the HD.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would reboot into Linux to see if it's a formatting issue or hardware issue... If Linux reads it see what the formatting is (type `mount`) and go from there.

Comment: Changing the partition type requires a partition manager and root privileges. Ubuntu definitely doesn't do this on its own. [How to Repair a Damaged Partition Table or MBR](http://geekyprojects.com/storage/how-to-repair-a-damaged-partition-table-or-mbr/) might help you.

Comment: I have sometimes found [ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) to be helpful in this situation. I haven't ever had it happen with Windows 7, though.

Comment: @user55325 and others, but I'm using Win7 right now, I wont have access to any Linux for a long time

Comment: Download and boot from a Linux LiveCD then.

Comment: If you really think that Ubuntu formatted the partition, try installing an ext2 file system driver for Windows - http://www.fs-driver.org/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/ will do the trick of mounting the drive in Windows. If however the drive is corrupted these will not help you - a Linux boot CD and Dennis' link is your best bet.

Comment: This sounds like it was simply hardware failure.  You need to boot to a Linux Boot CD at this point to confirm.  If the drive was formatted the data that was on it is likely gone.